# Unix command: ls -d */ but i only want to see the folders, not the files

Tags: unix

I am on UNIX environment. What I want to achieve is to navigate to a directory, and print out all its folders. For example:

> /user/Mike/data/

In the above directory, it has 50 folders. I want to only see the 50 folders in this directory. I used the following command:

> ls -d */

However, it will also show all the files within this directory. Is there a way for us to eliminate the listing for files by using my command above?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem "*it will also show all the files within this directory*". Please [edit] your question and show a [mre]: What files and directories do you have? What is the actual and expected output of `ls -d */`? Show the output of `type ls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options that I can think of:

`ls -l | grep ^d`, but this stats the output.

`find * -maxdepth 0 -type d`